# Generating complex single SQL query with Rails Arel from chunks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I'm really was surprised using Arel to build single composite sql query, when found that Arel's things are not chainable.

After long googling I found single solution. It uses 'reflect' custom method, and idea is to recursively instantiate new builder classes.. No matter.

For example, how I'm  tryed:

```
e = Arel::Table.new(:events)
a = e.where(e[:id].eq(1))

if (smth)  { a.where(e[:name].eq('joe')) } # not works
```

Is impossible to chain it somehow together. My plans were crumble to pieces.. Okay, I already implement it manually.

However, it is not good idea, because I should prevent any sql-injections traps , etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
e.where(e[:id].eq(1).and(e[:name].eq('joe'))
```

I don't really get why you would want to use Arel though as this is a trivial task with the  ActiveRecord query interface:

```
Event.where(id: 1, name: 'joe')
# calls to merge are additive 
Event.where(id: 1).where(name: 'joe')
# you can also programmatically merge scopes together
Event.where(id: 1).merge(Event.where(name: 'joe'))
```

Comment: because I have no models, I using remote MySQL connection to fetch some data, it's a foreign db server. I agree, that maybe Arel is not a key for such task.. But I can't find any alternative  .   It should be safe, prevents any SQL injetions, etc

Comment: I see your example with arel chain expression, but my chaining is relates on different conditions, for example: e[:name ] should not be appended, if my request params not contain such filter attribute

Comment: I would really just create models instead - you're not saving yourself any work and most likely making a mess if you try to do MVC without the M. And yes you can still use ActiveRecord if you have an existing legacy DB.

Comment: No, basically I not need any MVC with this. I suppose, it will be much quickly to resolve this task with sql-producing using oldest kindly strings concatenations.. :/

Comment: That's a bad conclusion - but whatever floats your boat I guess.

Comment: Bad conclusion is left it not resolved, without any solutions..  I guess this is a long  term discussion, and I need any temporary workaround